# Update the TextBox.Text in Usercontrol from everywhere

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'm facing an issue that seems recurrent and with a lot of solutions but, I apologize, I cannot/not able apply in my case. Let me summarize the topology: I have a main windows (**MainWindow**) with a grid and, in the bottom cell I put an user control written by me (**UC_StatusMonitor**) with a textbox inside the user control (**LBL_CONN_Message**) where I want to update with result of operations (e.g. "*Connected to device X*", "*Impossible to read data from Y*", "*Missing fields*" etc etc). This is basically used to inform the user if something is right or wrong. I understood I have to use Dependancy to solve this issue but my implementation doesn't work (for sure I missed something).

Let me show the code:

**MainWindows.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="LUX.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LUX"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="LUX" Name ="MainForm" Height="600" Width="800"  MinHeight="600" MinWidth="800">

    <Border Padding="10">

        <Grid Name="Main_Grid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- others controls ....   -->


            <!-- Monitor   -->
            <StackPanel Name="Stack_Monitor" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid Name="BottomBar" Height="20">
                    <local:UC_StatusMonitor Height="100" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>



    </Border>
</Window>
```

Then the code for the Control

**UC_StatusMonitor.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="LUX.UC_StatusMonitor"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LUX"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid Name="UCR_Base" Background="White">
        <WrapPanel>
            ...
            <TextBox Name="LBL_CONN_Message" Margin = "10 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, ElementName=control}"/>
            ...
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**UC_StatusMonitor.xaml.cs**

```
namespace LUX {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StatusMonitor.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UC_StatusMonitor : UserControl
    {
        Button[] MenuButtons;

        //// The dependency property which will be accessible on the UserControl
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyTextProperty", typeof(string), typeof(UC_StatusMonitor), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

        public string MyTextProperty
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyTextPropertyProperty, value); }
```

So, I'm expecting that, everywhere (in all the classes into the workspace, I declared a status monitor static object), I should use an instruction like

> MyTextProperty = "Connected";

and then see this message on the textbox into user control.

Obviously, doesn't happen :(

Thanks and best regards

Comment: I do not recommand you to do it this way, you would have better time to use some kind of message systems. If you want to go that way try to put the MyTextProperty in public static string etc.. instead of the DependencyProperty. then to class.MyTextProperty = "Connected"
FYI: http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger

Comment: You are not seeing anything because the `DataContext` of you `UC` is inherited from the parent. So calling `Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, ElementName=control}"` has NO effect as there is nothing in the xaml with the name `control`.

Comment: Not sure to completely understood: I added to the class UC_StatusMonitor the following line 'public static string MyTextProperty;' and theoretically I can call with 'UC_StatusMonitor.MyTextProperty = "Test";', am I right?

Comment: I hope my answer helped you or at least pointed you in the right direction. I would appreciate it if you would return the favor for the effort that I put into helping you. Regards XAMlMAX

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the `UserControl` to work with Binding.
Here is how I have done it:
`UserControlWithBinding.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SO_app.UserControlWithBinding"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Name="IAmGroot"> <!-- Name this grid as you want as this is what we will use for internal Binding -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/><!-- Because this grid is bound to the control it self you will always use this property, unless you rename it :-) -->
</Grid>
```

Now the code behind of the `UserControlWithBinding.xaml.cs`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for UserControlWithBinding.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class UserControlWithBinding : UserControl
{
    public UserControlWithBinding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IAmGroot.DataContext = this;// this is where we set the data context for the grid so it uses the UserControl and not the inherited one. This will allow us to have the DataContext for User Control to be still inherited but the grid will look into a UserControl as an object to assign it to it's data context.
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Status.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(string), typeof(UserControlWithBinding), new PropertyMetadata(null));//note that I am using null and not string.Empty


}
```

---

Now let's use our control in xaml:

```
<local:UserControlWithBinding Status="{Binding PropertyThatYouWantToBindThisControlsText}"/>
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a clarification, with "PropertyThatYouWantToBindThisControlsText" are you referring to?

Comment: You would use that instead of `MyTextProperty = "Connected";` in your VM you would have a property that would say `string Status {get;set;}//with INPC` and that would then populate the text. Hope this makes sense?